# vSphere timeout during post-login

Tags: vpn, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

During a login to VMware ESXi 5.1.0 the login verification is done. After that the process is waiting until timeout. Connection is done through a VPN tunnel.

Firewall rules are ok. On a second system, with the same configuration, everything works fine.

A direct connection in the same subnet, worked.
VMware ESXi was reinstalled twice.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I applied the same firewall rules and config to the second system (same hardware & software configuration), which works fine.
Firewall doesn't block anything according to the logs.

Comment: Hmmm... how odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the static IP, now it works. 
It propably wasn't chache-related as I reinstalled the whole machine before. Especially weird, as other services like HTTP, SSH etc. worked just fine.